# How can I insert an image into a pdf without saving either to a file?

Tags: node.js, qr-code, pdfmake

I am using [pdfMake](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfmake) to create a pdf and use it as an email attachment. Right now, I am only trying to create a QR code and place it inside of the newly created pdf.

I am using [qr-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qr-image) to generate the QR code.

Here is what I have so far to create the pdf (using [SendGrid v3](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/api_v3.html) api for mail delivery).

```
const docDefinition = {
    pageSize: 'A4',
    pageMargins: [40, 60, 40, 60],
    content: [
        'First paragraph',
        'Another paragraph, this time a little bit longer to make sure, this line will be divided into at least two lines',
        {
            image: qr.image(object.uid),
            width: 400
        },
    ]
};

let pdf;
pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).getBase64(function (encodedString) {
    pdf = encodedString;
    ...
    'attachments': [{
        'filename': 'attachment.pdf',
        'type': 'application/pdf',
        'content': pdf
    }],
    ...
}
```

The error I a getting back is:

```
Error getting event document:  invalid image, images dictionary should contain dataURL entries (or local file paths in node.js)
```

If I remove the image property and just send some sample text, everything works. So I know the PDF is getting generated, I'm just not setting up the QR image correctly.

I do not want to save the image if possible - I'd like to generate, attach and send.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In hopes that this will help someone else, here is what I came up with that works.

```
const qr_svg = qr.imageSync(object.uid, { type: 'png' });
const qr_str = 'data:image/png;base64,' + qr_svg.toString('base64');

const docDefinition = {
    pageSize: 'A4',
    pageMargins: [40, 60, 40, 60],
    content: [
        'First paragraph',
        'Another paragraph, this time a little bit longer to make sure, this line will be divided into at least two lines',
        {
            image: qr_str,
            width: 400
        },
    ]
};
```

I was in fact, incorrectly passing the image to the pdf. All credit goes to [Tim Krins](https://github.com/alexeyten/qr-image/issues/16)